# how to set permissions of all the folders and all the files in as few steps as possible CHMOD

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, chmod

I am trying to set permissions of all of my folders to 775
and all the files (documents) to 644
There are many MANY files and Folders. All of those files and folders are contained in a single Folder.

I was wondering if there was a way to do it quickly!!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find somedir/ \( -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} + -true \) -o \( -exec chmod 0644 {} + \)
```

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what this is, but somehow I feel a big surge of gratitude rushing out of my gut.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side i would rather ask and look like an idiot than not ask and feel like one! !! somedir is supposed to be the root directory??

Comment: `somedir/` is supposed to be the "single folder" in the question.

Comment: and after I am done executing this command, all the folders inside the root folders will have their permissions set to 775 recursively. And all the files in the root folder and in other folders inside root folders will have their permissions set to 644, is that correct???

Comment: So this means, I have to do this for each and every folder inside the root folder?

Comment: All directories will be set 0775, and everything else will be set 0644, recursively. You do it once, pointing at the "single folder" and it will handle all the contents.